# IE does not fires events using event attribute if <script> tag used in

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I recently faced to a strange bug (or something) in IE behavior is described blow. **(For quick conclusion, read the bottom of the question titled "edited")**.
suppose i have an input tag in the middle of some other `div` tags:

```
<input type="text" name ="foo" id="foo" value="2" onfocus="alert('foo')" />
```

You expect browser to alerts when ever `input` get focused, right? every browsers work as desired except `IE`. So i decided to play around it a little bit.
First, I edited the script using `F12 developer tool` in `IE`, And put a harmless space-bar after `onfocus="alert('foo' )` **Then it worked!!!**.
Every time i edit some where in the `onfocus` statement, from then on, the browser work as expected. but when refreshing, it gone.
Then i put `<input>` tag in outer div **And it Worked**.
My first guess was that

> may be event suppressed/stopped to propagate some where in the middle.

So i used [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/jQuery/Trackingeventpropagationwithbubbleandcapturehandlers.htm) code to track event chain. the event captured/bobbled like a charm. But this code used `addEventListener()` function in order to log every propagation and traverse.
Then i put `<input>` tag back in to the middle `<div>` but this time, I used `addEventListener()` function to attach handler to `focus` event, **And again It Worked**. But for this particular situation, I rather not to use `addEventListener()`.

It's good to know that, outer `DIVs` are loaded on `page-load` but inner 'DIVs' are loaded by an **ajax call**.
So my second guess is that:

> May be there is a bug with ajax loading content in `IE`

It's also good to know that, it doesn't matter what event do you call, It just stop working!!!.

By the way, I'm using `IE 11.0.32`

Any suggestion/explanation about what just happened
And any idea about what to do to get `IE` work with `event attributes` would be appreciated.

------------------------- Editted -------------------------------
After some more investigations, i understand that `IE` shows this behavior when i put `<script>` tag in my `.cshtml` file.
For instance, `<input type="text" name ="foo" id="foo" value="2" onfocus="alert('foo')" /> <script></script>`  wont work. but without `<script>` tag, It'll work.
It seams, It'll delete `onfocus` event from DOM, and when a change has made, then it'll put it back in to the element.
does any one have this experience?

Comment: You might want to tell us which version of IE is having the problem.  All versions are broken in their own way.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I use `IE 11.0.32` (just edited in the main question). ;-D

Comment: Is there any chance of a working example? A problem which is version specific is often hard to get to grips with without seeing it for yourself.

Comment: @DBS I afraid not. because the circumstances in the main project is complicated (many client-side frameworks & components...), and i don't know (at the moment) what part could damage the scenario.